# Detect whether a font is bold/italic on iOS?

Tags: ios, uifont

Given a UIFont or a CTFont, how can I tell whether the font is bold/italic?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Looking at the font's name won't always work. Consider the font "Courier Oblique" (which is italic) or "HoeflerText-Black" (which is bold), Neither of those contain "bold" or "italic" in their names.

Given a font as a `CTFontRef`, the proper way to determine whether it's bold or italic is to use the `CTFontGetSymbolicTraits` function:

```
CTFontRef font = CTFontCreateWithName((CFStringRef)@"Courier Oblique", 10, NULL);
CTFontSymbolicTraits traits = CTFontGetSymbolicTraits(font);
BOOL isItalic = ((traits & kCTFontItalicTrait) == kCTFontItalicTrait);
BOOL isBold = ((traits & kCTFontBoldTrait) == kCTFontBoldTrait);
NSLog(@"Italic: %i Bold: %i", isItalic, isBold);
CFRelease(font);
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this is a really clean way of doing this. One more question. Let's say I have a CTFont, how can I make it bold?

Comment: Use the `CTFontCreateCopyWithSymbolicTraits` function.

Comment: ```isItalic``` doesn't work with Superclarendon, Marion and Gill Sans fonts.

Answer (score 45):

#### iOS7 Font Descriptor

No reason to use Core Text, you can simply ask UIFont for the fontDescriptor.

```
        UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17.0f];
        UIFontDescriptor *fontDescriptor = font.fontDescriptor;
        UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits fontDescriptorSymbolicTraits = fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits;
        BOOL isBold = (fontDescriptorSymbolicTraits & UIFontDescriptorTraitBold) != 0;
```

Going forward this is probably the easiest way to ask about the traits of a font.

Comment: Don't cast `uint32_t` to `BOOL`, it will cause you problems. Use `BOOL isBold = (fontDescriptorSymbolicTraits & UIFontDescriptorTraitBold) != 0` or `BOOL isBold = !!(fontDescriptorSymbolicTraits & UIFontDescriptorTraitBold)` instead.

Answer (score 41):

If you want to do this with **Swift**:

```
extension UIFont {
    var isBold: Bool {
        return fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits.contains(.traitBold)
    }
    
    var isItalic: Bool {
        return fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits.contains(.traitItalic)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let font: UIFont = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .headline)
if font.isBold {
  print("it's bold..")
}
```

Comment: @JanGreve please reconsider your downvote, Answering old questions when there's new solutions available is a good thing, and I added Swift tag for clarity.

Comment: I removed the swift tag again. There is no way the author could've meant to ask for swift, so your edit clearly conflicts with the author's intend. Other than that, you are right; a new objective-c technique would have been fine.

Comment: Note: this is currently being [discussed on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317716/are-only-tags-allowed-that-the-author-could-have-intended) @Jan

Answer (score 11):

Answer for **Swift 3/4** based on Arjan's answer:

```
extension UIFont {
    var isBold: Bool {
        return fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits.contains(.traitBold)
    }

    var isItalic: Bool {
        return fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits.contains(.traitItalic)
    }
}
```