# ios share extension post button title

Tags: ios, ios8-share-extension

I want to change the title of post buttons in SLComposeServiceViewController.
I managed to get the UIButton:

```
NSArray* subviews =[self.navigationController.navigationBar subviews];
UIButton* postButton =[subviews lastObject];
```

and i tried to set title like this:

```
[postButton setTitle:@"Save" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

but the title not changed.

Can anyone help me with this?

I saw Evernote's share extension on my iPad and it looks like this:
[image]

**UPDATE**

**My Solution:**

I found solution for my question,I removed the original navigation bar and create custom nav bar.

I have two nav bar:
1. with "cancel"\"save" buttons
2. with "back" button

and I change them when navigate to other viewcontroller
(in my case I needed to upload file and user need select location from list)

NOTE: if you not implement `configurationItems` you need only the first nav bar. (just call to set custom nav bar from `viewDidAppear`

So my code is here:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationBar *customNavBar;

-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];  
    self.customNavBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:self.navigationController.navigationBar.bounds];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar removeFromSuperview];
    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:self.customNavBar];
    [self setCancelSaveNavigationItem];
}
```

setCancelSaveNavigationItem--> called from viewDidAppear of shareViewController

```
-(void)setCancelSaveNavigationItem
{
    UINavigationItem *newItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] init];
    UIBarButtonItem *cancelBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel",nil)  style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(cancelButtonTapped:)];
    UIBarButtonItem *saveBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Done",nil)  style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(saveButtonTapped:)];
    newItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelBarButtonItem;
    newItem.rightBarButtonItem = saveBarButtonItem;
    [self.customNavBar setItems:@[newItem]];
    [self.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem:cancelBarButtonItem];
    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:saveBarButtonItem];
    if(self.item.value == nil){
        saveBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
    }
}
```

setBackNavigationItem--> called in `configurationItems` -->in `self.item.tapHandler` function

```
-(void)setBackNavigationItem
{
    UINavigationItem *newItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] init];
    UIBarButtonItem *selectBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Select",nil)  style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(selectButtonTapped:)];
    UIBarButtonItem *backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"❮ %@", NSLocalizedString(@"Back",nil)]  style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(backButtonTapped:)];
    newItem.leftBarButtonItem = backBarButtonItem;
    newItem.rightBarButtonItem = selectBarButtonItem;
    [self.customNavBar setItems:@[newItem]];
    [self.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem:backBarButtonItem];
    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:selectBarButtonItem];
}
```

Handle buttons tapped:

```
- (void)backButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    if([self.navigationController.viewControllers count] ==2){
        [self setCancelSaveNavigationItem];
    }
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)cancelButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    [self cancel];
}

- (void)selectButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    ...
    [self setCancelSaveNavigationItem];
    [self popConfigurationViewController];
}

- (void)saveButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    ...
    [self cancel];
}
```

And it's work for me!!!

The result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure UIButton* postButton =[subviews lastObject]; is really what you try to customize? Try to NSLog it's title.

Comment: @user3344236 Yes, I tried it, so I assumed it post button...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code:

```
NSArray* subviews =[self.navigationController.navigationBar subviews];
UIButton* postButton =[subviews lastObject];
```

...is a **really bad idea**. It only works because the post button is in `subviews` and is the last item in the array. But the content of `subviews` is undocumented and might change at any time. Also, since there's no public API for this button, it's entirely possible that there's framework code to prevent or override changes to the button text-- so even if we assume you have the right UI element, you still might not be able to change it.

Evernote's UI is almost certainly a full custom design that only resembles `SLComposeServiceViewController`. Share extensions are not required to use `SLComposeServiceViewController`, that's just there for convenience. If it doesn't meet your needs, design your own.

Update: out of curiosity I unzipped the Evernote IPA and had a look at `EvernoteShare.appex` with [nm](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/nm.1.html). There's no reference to `SLComposeServiceViewController`, which confirms that Evernote is not using that class in their extension.

Comment: "it's entirely possible that there's framework code to prevent or override changes to the button text". I believe you're absolutely right: [I tried](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31770293/3765705) iterating through all the subviews, more as a proof of concept than for actual use in my app, and while I successfully get to the two buttons, I can't override their color nor text. Too bad!

Comment: Well, I worked a bit more on this and I was able to make it work on iOS 8.4 - see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31770293/3765705) here on Stack Overflow; I don't believe anymore that Apple has put in place code to prevent this kind of changes, but still I'm not sure this should be done. Let's say it was a fun way to spend a sunday morning ;)

Comment: @cdf1982 I shared my solution in my question, and it's work on all versions. I just make new nav bar and I remove the original from subViews.

Answer (score 15):

Simply in `viewDidAppear`

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItem?.title = "Save"
```

Comment: If use objective-c you can insert into configurationItems function this code: [[self navigationController] navigationBar].topItem.rightBarButtonItem.title = @"Save";

Comment: Thanks very much! I just need to change the Post to Save and nothing else, this worked very well and seems to be not that fragile!

Comment: I had to use `viewDidLoad()`.